# Error in Jade template: character "d" not allowed in prolog

Tags: pug, webstorm

When I am creating this simple Jade document:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title welcome
    body hi, world
```

I get this error message in the console:

```
/usr/bin/jade user_form.jade
/usr/bin/jade:user_form.jade:1:0:E: character "d" not allowed in prolog
/usr/bin/jade:user_form.jade:5:19:E: end of document in prolog
/usr/bin/jade:E: cannot find "user_form.dsl"; tried "user_form.dsl", "/usr/share/sgml/user_form.dsl"
/usr/bin/jade:E: specification document does not have the DSSSL architecture as a base architecture

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I launch the node.js application this template works file so why does WebStorm return this error message?

Comment: This should have been sent to the WebStorm team as a bug, there is no issue with your pug code.